# PHP 5 type hinting (passing array of objects of type A to the function)

Tags: php, casting, type-hinting

I have a function that takes argument of type `A` (in PHP 5):

```
function f1(A a){...}
```

I also have an array that I decode from `$_POST['val']` value and send it to some other function `f2`:

```
$array1 =  json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['val']));
f2($array1);
```

Now I want to call `f1` on each of the array's elements inside of `f2`:

```
function f2(array $a){
    foreach($a as $element){
        f1($element);
}
```

But I get an error:

```
Argument 1 passed to f1() must be an instance of A, instance of stdClass given
```

When I put `if($element instanceof A)` inside `f2` I get `FALSE`, but I can call on that `$element` the `A`'s methods propertly.

How to 'tell' `f1` that the type is right?

Using `print_r` on the `array1` (`name` and `sourceId` are in `A`):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => connect
        [sourceId] => 12
    )

)
```

Comment: `stdClass` is not `A`. It also doesn't have methods. You won't ever get something of type `A` out of `json_decode`. You need to construct your `A` objects out of the data before passing them to `f1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output of json_decode is an object of type stdClass so it is normal to get that error. It is not easy in PHP to cast from one object type to another but you can use this trick:

```
function f2(array $a){
    foreach($a as $element){
        f1 ( unserialize ( preg_replace ( "/O:\d+:\"\w+\":(.*)/", "O:1:\"A\":$1", serialize ($element) ) ) )
}
```

this dirty trick actually cast stdClass to object of type A.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A second parameter to json_decode is a boolean, set it to 'true' if you want an array.

```
$array1 =  json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['val']), true);
```

Also read up on security. Blithely trusting the data you get from $_POST is a bad idea.

Comment: I set it to true, but my main problem remains the same. The $_POST data is the data from jQuery/AJAX, but it's off-topic ;-)

Comment: My standard answer for finding out why data which should work, doesn't - print it (or log it to a file so you can look at it), so you can see exactly what you are getting. Chances are, you aren't getting what you think, and it will be very obvious when you look at it.

Comment: @AlisterBulman Just curious, what is dangerous in trusting $_POST in his/her case?

Comment: It depends where the data ends up, but, for example, if it was doing into a database without filtering.... http://xkcd.com/327/